# How to set image_strip_add() Width?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, scene, image-sequence

This Python Script works in Blender 2.79, inserting an image to the Video sequencer. But i can't set the Width (scale). Any Ideas?

```
sequences = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences 
obj = sequences.new_image(
        name=file_name,
        filepath=filePath,
        channel=channel,
        frame_start=int(frame_start)        
        )
                
obj.use_translation=True  
obj.blend_alpha=0.0
#obj.scale doesnt work
obj.scale=[0.5,0.5]
```

Comment: I think your missing the Z-scale setting.  From documentation: ```Type    float array of 3 items in [-inf, inf], default (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)```... i.e., array of *3* items required.  So try ```obj.scale=[0.5,0.5,1.0]``` or ```obj.scale=[0.5,0.5,0.5]```

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is my solution.
found here: https://blenderartists.org/t/solved-add-effect-strip-transform-for-image-vse-lm18/688456

Set a Context first: `window = bpy.context.window`

```
def setTransformer(scene,filename):

    
    sequence = scene.sequence_editor
    bpy.ops.sequencer.select_all(action="DESELECT")

    mystrip = sequence.sequences_all[filename]
    sequence.active_strip = mystrip

    screen, area = find_sequencer_area()
    window = bpy.context.window
    location = {
        "window": window,
        "scene": scene,
        "name": 'test',
        "area": area,
        "screen": screen,
        "region": area.regions[0]
         }

    bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add(location, type="TRANSFORM")
    return lastSequence("Transform")
    
def lastSequence(mod="Transform"):
    transform_sequences=bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all
    lastKey=False;
    for key in transform_sequences.keys():
        
        if re.search(r"^("+str(mod)+")",key):
          
            lastKey=key
        
            
  
    return transform_sequences[lastKey]    


 obj = sequences.new_image(
        name=file_name,
        filepath=filePath,
        channel=channel,
        frame_start=int(frame_start)        
        )
transformer[file_name]=setTransformer(scenes1,file_name)
transformer[file_name].use_uniform_scale = False
transformer[file_name].scale_start_y =123
transformer[file_name].scale_start_x =432
```